# project reference is not set in msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I am using MSBUild to compile my solution. In my solution i have project "A". Project "A" internally call (projetc ref call) to project "B". But project "B" is not a part of my solution.

When i compile with MSBuild i am getting error "**The type or namespace name 'XYZ' does not exist in the namespace 'Utilities' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**"

When i compile in VS IDE (2008), I am able to compile the solution.

Solution
--> Project "A" (Part of solution)
-------> Project "B" (not a part of solution)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use solution references, use project references, and your build will work from both the solution and the command line.  See [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx) for an explanation of why solution dependencies are bad.

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer but project "B" is not added in the solution.

Comment: <Project>{58D72C0F-57F2-45A9-8A61-2CD31CE2AA58}</Project>
<Name>XYZ.Utilities.Instrumentation</Name>                          Only above info is available in the project file of project "A".

Comment: Both project "A" and "B" are part of the solution "2" and i can compile it from MSBuild. but project "b" is not a part of solution "1", i am getting the error "Solution file warning MSB4051: Project {957A5F25-F175-4168-9EC1-C9C0906E9686} is referencing a project with GUID {58D72C0F-57F2-45A9-8A61-2CD31CE2AA58}, but a project with this GUID was not found in the .SLN file". but when i compile it from VS IDE(2008), it's working fine.